# Probability matrices in an online game or how to approach matching players to maps to achieve better user experience

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Probably I had nonstandart question, but I hope to find some help and valueable advice.

Assume I have an online game with $n$ players (let's say $n$ is about 100.000).

There's also $m$ maps ($m$ is about 10) and every map goes with its probability (some of the maps played much more frequently than others).

So, assume there's $k$ rounds in which all the players are divided into battles randomly (20 people for one battle). After the division for battles I choose a map for every matched battle (the least map occured for all of the people participating in a current battle).

The problem is: players go crazy when they play several maps too frequently.

So I would like to build a mathematical model (not like simple simulation many times) to somehow measure/count the average 'angriness' of players (the 'angriness' is the maximum occurence of all the maps played for $k$ round). 
For example if the player played $k=5$ rounds
1st round - 1st map
2nd round - 1st map
3rd round - 5th map
4th round - 2nd map
5th round - 1st map,
then the angriness is 3 (1st map occured 3 times).

At this stage I'm stucked because I don't know what to do. I tried to search on the web some topics but didn't find anything. 
Also I tried to go into some stochastic processes. We can build a matrix $m$ x $n$ for every round ($a_{i,j}$ means the number of occurences of $i$-th map for $j$-th player). But it seems hard to calculate something in this huge model.

Again, THANKS in advance for any advice, thoughts, links, approaches or other help.

Comment: So you want your player to alternate as much as possible between maps? Why don't you just make the probabilities of each map equal? Or to get more in control keep a log of the last x maps the player played in and choose at random between the remaining ones, or some other thing.. what is the specific mathematical problem that's troubling you?

Comment: Yes, to keep several last maps for each player and choose the maps that's minimize the total angriness is the good idea.  
But I want to measure the expected angriness of a player to understand what's the number of last maps x should I keep for each player.

Answer (score 0):

If the probability of the $j$-th map is $p_j$, and $X_j$ the variable which counts how many times the map $p_j$ appears in $N$ rounds, then $X_j \sim Bi(N,p_j)$ is a binomial distribution; the mean is $$E[X_j] = Np_j$$

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not true.
At each round I'm trying to choose the best map for every 20 people chosen randomly. So the every next map isn't chosen randomly.  
Thus $X_j \equiv 0$ (mod 20) for every $j$.